# Show hidden Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I understand there were a lot of such issues. But a strange situation is happening with my option. Well, it’s not very clear. You can tell what is wrong.

I hide `activeFragment` if it is not `null`. Then I add a `Fragment` if it is not. And if there is, then I `show`. From the first time, everything works fine when I create it using the `add()` method or `replace()`. But if I go back and try to `show()` the already hidden Fragment, then it's just a white screen, there is no `Fragment`. What could be the problem?

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        if (activeFragment != null) {
            transaction.hide(activeFragment);
        }

        if (fm.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag);
        } else {
            transaction.show(fragment);
        }
        activeFragment = fragment;

        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```